# Using Class<T> as a Map key in Haxe

Tags: inversion-of-control, haxe

I'd like to store instances of models in a common provider using their classes or interfaces as a keys and then pop them up by class references. I have written some code:

```
class Provider {

    public function new() { }

    public function set<T:Any>(instance:T, ?type:Class<T>) {
        if (type == null)
            type = Type.getClass(instance);
        if (type != null && instance != null)
            map.set(type, instance);
    }

    public function get<T:Any>(type:Class<T>):Null<T> {
        return cast map.get(type);
    }

    var map = new Map<Class<Any>, Any>();

}
```

...alas, it's even doesn't compile.
Probably I have to use qualified class name as a key rather than class/interface reference? But I'd like to keep neat get function design that takes type as argument and returns object just of type taken, without additional type casting.

Is it possible or should I change my approach to this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue of using [`Class<T>`](https://api.haxe.org/Class.html) as a `Map` key come up every so often, [here](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/1971) is a related discussion. The naive approach of `Map<Class<T>, T>` fails to compile with something like this:

> Abstract haxe.ds.Map has no @:to function that accepts haxe.IMap<Class<Main.T>, Main.T>`

There's several different approaches to this problem:

- One can use [`Type`](https://api.haxe.org/Type.html?) reflection to obtain the fully qualified name of a class instance, and then use that as a key in a `Map<String, T>`:

  ```
  var map = new Map<String, Any>();
  var name = Type.getClassName(Main);
  map[name] = value;
  ```

  For convenience, you would probably want to have a wrapper that does this for you, such as [this `ClassMap` implementation](https://github.com/nadako/Ash-Haxe/blob/master/src/ash/ClassMap.hx).

---

- A simpler solution is to simply "trick" Haxe into compiling it by using  an empty structure type (`{}`) as the key type. This causes [`ObjectMap`](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/ds/ObjectMap.html?) to be chosen as the underlying map implementation.

  ```
  var map = new Map<{}, Any>();
  map[Main] = value;
  ```

  However, that allows you to use things as keys that are not of type `Class<T>`, such as:

  ```
  map[{foo: "bar"}] = value;
  ```

  ---
- The type safety issues of the previous approach can be remedied by using [this `ClassKey` abstract](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/1971#issuecomment-288173294):

  ```
  @:coreType abstract ClassKey from Class<Dynamic> to {} {}
  ```

  This still uses `ObjectMap` as the underlying map implementation due to the `to {}` [implicit cast](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-implicit-casts.html). However, using a structure as a key now fails at compile time:

  ```
  var map = new Map<ClassKey, Any>();
  map[{foo: "bar"}] = value; // No @:arrayAccess function accepts arguments [...]
  ```

Comment: Thanks for tips. I have solved my problem with `Type.getClassName` and `StringMap`. One drawback still left in interface `function set<T:Dynamic>(instance:T, ?type:Class<Dynamic>)` that doesn't check complementary of instance and provided type at compile time.

Comment: Have you tried `Class<T>` instead of `Class<Dynamic>`?

Comment: Sure I did, but this ain't work with interface implemented by instance -- type inference drop an error in compile time. So I have to break consistent signature of method for the purpose of flexibility.